# OpenGL Depth Test Errors

Tags: opengl, depth

I've been working on this problem for a while now.
My problem is that the sphere in the top image, is under-lapping the plane which should have a lower Z value. Although, when depth testing is disabled, it is resolved. But it favors draw order over actual fragment depth value. I was changing the depth mask out of desperation. ;)

```
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
rootObject.render(ambient);

GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_ONE, GL11.GL_ONE);
GL11.glDepthMask(false);
GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_EQUAL);

for(int i = 0; i < lights.size(); i++){
    lights.get(i).use();
    rootObject.render(lights.get(i).getProgram());
}

GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LESS);
GL11.glDepthMask(true);
```

-- Screenies:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

[image: depth issue1]

```
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

[image: depth issue2]

Comment: It is unclear what you asking. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: And why do you think you need to change `GL11.glDepthMask` ?

Comment: My problem is that the sphere in the top image, is under-lapping the plane which *should* have a lower Z value. Although, when depth testing is disabled, it is resolved. But it favors draw order over actual fragment depth value.

I was changing the depth mask out of desperation. ;)

Comment: @Ecumene Edit that into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem was my projection matrix. I found this error when I was switching vector math libraries. And I forgot transformations in javax's vecmath are row-major order. So I switched the near and far planes, and it worked perfectly.

```
(0.1f, 1000f) to (1000f, 0.1f)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you need to throw `glDepthMask` out.

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enable depth testing
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND); // Enable blending
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); // Common blending formula for transparency
rootObject.render(ambient); // Background

GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_ONE, GL11.GL_ONE); // This is uncommon blending formula ..
GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL); //<-- Less or Equal = LEqual

for(int i = 0; i < lights.size(); i++){
    lights.get(i).use();
    rootObject.render(lights.get(i).getProgram()); // spheres?
}
```

Comment: Still isn't working... Same result as the second image

Comment: You did not say - What is the desired result?

Comment: I wanted the sphere to be overlapping the plane, with depth testing. But when depth is enabled, the plane gets drawn **over** the spheres

Comment: Try also removing the `GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_ONE, GL11.GL_ONE);` It looks out of place too.

Comment: That's for the shader-light pass.